# How to create an xAPI (Tin Can) LRS (Learning Record Store) in C#

Tags: c#, rest, tin-can-api

I'm looking for some sample code to get me started on a C# based LRS.  I've read the xAPI spec from ADL's website and I've looked through all the sample code in their github repo but there just isn't anything good to start from except an example written in python/postgresql which is WAY out there for me.  I'm trying to stick with C#/SQL for my implementation.  Does anyone know where I can find some sample code to get started?  Perhaps you'd like to collaborate with me to develop it?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Mark, do you already have a C# implementation example?

Comment: No.  We finally got access to our own server and we are currently experimenting with Learning Locker.  It's php based though.

Comment: any luck with C# LRS?

Answer (score 1):

I found a few starting points (node.js, and php) but nothing complete in C# to work from.  Here's what I've found so far...

[Experience API Specification](https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec)

[Rustici Software's Repo (lots of clients but no LRS's)](https://github.com/RusticiSoftware)

[PHPCan, tinCaptivate and More](https://github.com/garemoko)

[Node.js and MongoDb](http://www.adlnet.gov/resources/tin-can-prototypes?type=software_downloads)

If you find anything new, please tack on to this!

Comment: There is a .NET library for previous specs but this has yet to be udpated to 1.0.0 specification

https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCanAPILibraryCSharp

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find the .Net implementation of the API :

http://tincan.codeplex.com/ and (preferably)

http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCan.NET/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score -2):

There is a .NET library forudpated to 1.0.0 specification

http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCan.NET/

All the class models are there, it is easily translated to a database schema for saving on your own end